# About transferring chunk

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

2016-03-15 11:42:23:610 INFO  [flightes4_2434]->[flightes4_2435] - transferring chunk #705 offset=371101709 size=4083... [OCopyDatabaseChunkTask]

Why transfer chunk when I started OrientDB in distributed mode?
What is it in the transfer chunk ?
And the process is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

By default `deployDatabase:true` in `distributed-config.json` configuration file, so the database is deployed to the starting server in small chunks.